# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack - Learn Python the Hard Way Ex: 13

Tags: python

I've looked through the questions that have already been answered but I am still confused. I've run the code 100 times and I keep getting the same "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" error so obviously something is not computing (see what I did there?) for me. Can someone look at my code and explain to me like you would a child what i've screwed up?

Obviously i've deviated from the terms in the lesson out of sheer frustration

What I have written is:

```py
from sys import argv

script, called, coding, confusing = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", called
print "Your second variable is:", coding
print "Your third variable is:", confusing
```

Is there a special something I should type in terminal or am I just missing bits of code?

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is a tuple containing the argument the script was called with. You need to pass your script the necessary number of arguments when you call it:

```
python myscript.py param_called param_coding param_confusing
```

To go further:

You are using a syntax called unpacking. This means the left hand side is not a single variable but rather a "sequence" (tuple) of variables. On the left hand side you need a sequence too that has the same number of elements, like a list or tuple. Each variable on the left hand side will be assigned the corresponding value from the right hand side. See [the tutorial about tuples and sequences](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (last paragraph).

About your left hand side, `argv` or better `sys.argv`, this is a tuple that contains the script name as first element and the command line parameters. See [argv](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html?highlight=argv#sys.argv).

All put together: you want to unpack `sys.argv` which is in the above example `("script.py", "param_called", "param_coding", "param_confusing")` into `script,called,coding,confusing`, so the variable `script` will be affected the string `"script.py"`, `called` the string `"param_called"`, etc.

The drawback of this method is that if the command line has too few or too many arguments, the unpacking fails.

Comment: Ok, at the risk of sounding very very dumb can you explain that a little further?

Comment: Yes, I'm gathering the links :)

Comment: @Cilyan: I edited to fix a typo, and while I was in the editor, also tried to clarify another sentence that seemed confusing to me. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Not at all, actually I swapped my left and right, as usual ;)

Comment: The `What You Should See` section of [Learn Python The hard Way Ex 13](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html) has also explanations on how to proceed and why it works like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but as specified in the instructions you must put 3 "arguments" into the command prompt

ex: $ python ex13.py called coding confusing 
the above prints this out to the command prompt:

The script is called: ex13.py
Your first variable is: called
Your second variable is: coding
Your third variable is: confused